# How to use pagination for displaying circles from Google+

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I have set maxResults to 10 and i want to know  how to use view more circles with nextpageToken and by clicking  View More button the next 10 circles have to display and goes  on till the last circles in Google+. Please help me fix this issue.
Please see my code below :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google+ JavaScript Quickstart</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
  </script>


  <!-- JavaScript specific to this application that is not related to API
     calls -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="gConnect">
    <button class="g-signin"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
        data-clientId="my client id"
        data-callback="onSignInCallback"
        data-theme="dark"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="authOps" style="display:none">
    <h2>User is now signed in to the app using Google+</h2>
    <p>If the user chooses to disconnect, the app must delete all stored
    information retrieved from Google for the given user.</p>

    <button id="disconnect" >Disconnect your Google account from this app</button>

    <h2>User's profile information</h2>
    <div id="profile"></div>

    <h2>User's friends that are visible to this app</h2>
    <div id="visiblePeople"></div>

    <p><a href="#" id="getMore" onClick="getMore()">View More</a></p>
    <h2>Authentication Logs</h2>
    <pre id="authResult"></pre>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var helper = (function() {
  var BASE_API_PATH = 'plus/v1/';

  return {
    /**
     * Hides the sign in button and starts the post-authorization operations.
     *
     * @param {Object} authResult An Object which contains the access token and
     *   other authentication information.
     */
    onSignInCallback: function(authResult) {
      gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
        $('#authResult').html('Auth Result:<br/>');
        for (var field in authResult) {
          $('#authResult').append(' ' + field + ': ' +
              authResult[field] + '<br/>');
        }
        if (authResult['access_token']) {
          $('#authOps').show('slow');
          $('#gConnect').hide();
          helper.profile();
          helper.people();
        } else if (authResult['error']) {
          // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
          // As an example, you can handle by writing to the console:
          console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
          $('#authResult').append('Logged out');
          $('#authOps').hide('slow');
          $('#gConnect').show();
        }
        console.log('authResult', authResult);
      });
    },

    /**
     * Calls the OAuth2 endpoint to disconnect the app for the user.
     */
    disconnect: function() {
      // Revoke the access token.
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
            gapi.auth.getToken().access_token,
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(result) {
          console.log('revoke response: ' + result);
          $('#authOps').hide();
          $('#profile').empty();
          $('#visiblePeople').empty();
          $('#authResult').empty();
          $('#gConnect').show();
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      });
    },

    /**
     * Gets and renders the list of people visible to this app.
     */
    people: function() {
      var request = gapi.client.plus.people.list({

        'userId': 'me',
        'collection': 'visible',
        'selfLink':'http://localhost/Google+/trail+.html',
        'maxResults':10,`enter code here`
        'items[]' : 'list',
        'nextPageToken': 'CAIQ0K3cq5DEtAIgAygB'


              });
      request.execute(function(people) {
        $('#visiblePeople').empty();
        $('#visiblePeople').append('Number of people visible to this app: ' +
            people.totalItems + '<br/>');




        for (var personIndex in people.items) {
          person = people.items[personIndex];



          $('#visiblePeople').append('<img src="' + person.image.url + '">');
           $('#visiblePeople').append(''+ person.displayName + '</br>'+ '</br>');



        }
      });
    },

    /**
     * Gets and renders the currently signed in user's profile data.
     */
    profile: function(){
      var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
      request.execute( function(profile) {
        $('#profile').empty();
        if (profile.error) {
          $('#profile').append(profile.error);
          return;
        }
        $('#profile').append(
            $('<p><img src=\"' + profile.image.url + '\"></p>'));
        $('#profile').append(
            $('<p>Hello ' + profile.displayName + '!<br />Tagline: ' +profile.tagline + '!<br />Email id: ' +profile.email +
            + '<br />About: ' + profile.aboutMe + '</p>'));
        if (profile.cover && profile.coverPhoto) {
          $('#profile').append(
              $('<p><img src=\"' + profile.cover.coverPhoto.url + '\"></p>'));

        }
      });
    }
  };
})();

/**
 * jQuery initialization
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#disconnect').click(helper.disconnect);
  if ($('[data-clientid="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"]').length > 0) {
    alert('This sample requires your OAuth credentials (client ID) ' +
        'from the Google APIs console:\n' +
        '    https://code.google.com/apis/console/#:access\n\n' +
        'Find and replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with your client ID.'
    );
  }


  });

/**
 * Calls the helper method that handles the authentication flow.
 *
 * @param {Object} authResult An Object which contains the access token and
 *   other authentication information.
 */
function onSignInCallback(authResult) {
  helper.onSignInCallback(authResult);
}
function getMore()
{
helper.people();

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there may be a couple of issues here. You seem to have at least some of the gist of how to use people.list, but you seem to be trying to add some of the response fields to the request field. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list for full details of the request parameters and the expected response.

On the first call, you only need to pass the `userId` and `collection` parameters. Since you want to limit the page size, you'll need to pass `maxResults` as well, so your call will look something like

```
var requestParams = {
  'userId': 'me',
  'collection': 'visible',
  'maxResults': 10
};
gapi.client.plus.people.list( requestParams ).execute(peopleCallback);
```

The parameter passed to `peopleCallback()` will contain the results, including a `nextPageToken`, which you will need to pass on subsequent calls to get additional items. You can store this token in a global variable, or as an attribute in your helper object, and process the other fields you need. So it might look something like this:

```
peopleCallback: function(response){
  nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  items.forEach(function(item){
    $('#visiblePeople').append(''+person.displayName+'');
  });
}
```

The next time the "List more" button is called, you need to include the nextPageToken as part of your request, so the call would look something more like this:

```
var requestParams = {
  'userId': 'me',
  'collection': 'visible',
  'maxResults': 10,
  'pageToken': nextPageToken
};
gapi.client.plus.people.list( requestParams ).execute(peopleCallback);
```

Subsequent calls will get a new nextPageToken which should be passed the next time you're making a call to continue getting the list.

I leave it as an exercise to determine the best way for you to handle the differences between these calls (passing a token vs not), initializing the visiblePeople list, and other issues specific to your code structure.

One important caveat on what you're trying to do, however. Your question title suggests that you're trying to get circles of a person - this will not give you that info. The people.list call will give you people, not circles, that a person is willing to publicly say are added to a circle. A user may choose to not provide this information, or may choose to only provide a subset of the information, and you will not know what specifically named circles a person may have been added to